# Google Cloud Platform - API Gateway Cannot PUT/DELETE Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-gateway

I'm struggling to pass the path params from my gateway to the actual endpoints and I use PUT method to do the update and DELETE method to do a delete action in API which is built with Google Cloud Functions.

Here is my API Gateway Config:

```
# openapi2-functions.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: cpd-api
  description: API Gateway Config
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /users/{user_id}:
    put:
      summary: Update an existing user
      operationId: update-user-cpd
      parameters:
        - name: user_id
          in: path
          description: User ID to be updated
          required: true
          type: string
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://asia-southeast2-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/cpd_user
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      responses:
        '200':
          description: User updated successfully
          schema:
            type: object
    delete:
      summary: Delete an existing user
      operationId: delete-user-cpd
      parameters:
        - name: user_id
          in: path
          description: User ID to be deleted
          required: true
          type: string
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://asia-southeast2-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/cpd_user
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      responses:
        '200':
          description: User deleted successfully
          schema:
            type: object
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Get Users data
      operationId: get-users-cpd
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://asia-southeast2-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/cpd_user
      responses:
        '200':
          description: User retrieved successfully
          schema:
            type: object
    post:
      summary: Create a new user
      operationId: create-user-cpd
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://asia-southeast2-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/cpd_user
      responses:
        '200':
          description: User created successfully
          schema:
            type: object
```

If I call the Functions URL directly with PUT/DELETE method it's working as expected.
e.g. `PUT https://asia-southeast2-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/cpd_user/1`

But, when I try to call it by using the API Gateway URL it gives me below errors with 404 HTTP Status:

```
Cannot PUT /users/1

Cannot DELETE /users/1
```

Here is the cpd_user index.js file.
I use express JS to define the routes

```
const _utils = require('./utils');
const _controller = require('./controllers');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const UserController = new _controller.UserController();
app.get('/', _utils.jwtFilter, UserController.getUserAction);
app.post('/', UserController.createUserAction);
app.delete('/{user_id}', _utils.jwtFilter, UserController.deleteUserAction);
app.put('/{user_id}', _utils.jwtFilter, UserController.updateUserAction);

exports.cpdUser = app;
```

I have checked the log but I didn't get any useful info there.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I have 2 questions for you. 1) Please post the code for the Cloud function backend service "cpd_user" by editing your question. 2) Does this Cloud function backend have all the GET,PUT,POST,DELETE methods with it? Each of your get, post, put, delete must have their corresponding service URLs in the 'path' of OpenAPI spec config file. I see for all the methods, there is same URL "https://asia-southeast2-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/cpd_user" provided.

Comment: Also after the API gateway URL has been created for the API config, you can test the API routes by calling "curl https://gateway_id-<hash>-uc.gateway.dev/users" for  GET requests, curl DELETE https://gateway_id-<hash>-uc.gateway.dev/users/1 for DELETE requests, curl POST https://gateway_id-<hash>-uc.gateway.dev/users --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"id": 1, "firstname": "Vikram", "lastname": "Shinde"}' for POST requests.

Comment: Added the index.js code. I'm using express to define the routes. And also if I test the functions directly (not using the API gateway host), it's working for all of those method.

Comment: Actually, because it's a CRUD for user resource, so I make it in one GCP Functions. Is that OK to do that? Or I have to create every CRUD process into a single GCP functions?

Comment: Just wanted to check if you have done the following : We need to export the app so that the Cloud functions will understand to use it as an access point.
Here, you have : exports.cpdUser = app;
In the Cloud functions settings, set 'Function to execute' as cpdUser as mentioned in the [article here](https://medium.com/mindvalley-technology/using-express-js-for-routing-inside-the-gcp-cloud-functions-9d2ef564c396)

Comment: The function doesn't know or care about the OpenAPI spec, so if you deploy a function that expects https://asia-southeast2-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/cpd_user/1, that's totally fine but the API Gateway isn't going to send a request there
Basically, you need to update your app routes in the function to expect a request to the fully appended path as defined in Open API spec.The OP's function is listening for a request of: /cpd_users/{id}  and is getting a request of: /cpd_users/users/{id} which doesn't match so the function correctly says "i can't handle this request".

Comment: Was I able to resolve your issue?